# XSS attack being blocked by the browser

Tags: web-browser, xss, reflected-xss

I'm trying to validate / test and XSS attack; however when I navigate to the page, the browser (tried on Chrome and Edge) tells me:

> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
> is invoked via document.write. The network
> request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a
> future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this
> page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more
> details.

I visited the reference page, but it's not very clear on exactly what is happening.  Is there a way to turn this off so that I can validate the XSS attack?

Comment: The link says that `document.write(<external address>)` is what's trigering it

Comment: I would simply try a different browser. Chrome and edge use the same chromium core.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39610983/10264972